# Prove that $f$ has a global maximum given a product of Taylor polinomials

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:f\in C^{\infty},f\left(1\right)=0$ and the product of its Taylor polinomials of order 2 in $x_{0}=0$ and $x_{0}=1$ be $P(x)=x^{4}-2x^{3}+2x^{2}-x$. Prove that $f$ has a global maximum in $\left(0,1\right)$

I cannot solve this problem! I expanded the Taylor polinomals and multiplied them in orden to compare the result with $P(x)$ but I messed up! I think there is another path. Also, I dont know how this would help to prove the statement

Comment: Whatever happens on the interval $(0,1)$, the global maximum of the function can be elsewhere. Did you mean local maximum?

Comment: Absolute maximum on $(0,1)$ might be a better expression.

Comment: @KittyL What do you understand under "absolute maximum"?

Comment: Here is a sketch of the idea. Compare the coefficients of like terms of the product of Taylor polynomials with $P(x)$. The constant terms will give you $f(0)[\frac{1}{2}f''(1)-f'(1)]=0$. So either factor could be zero. Let's say $f(0)=0$. Using other equations you get from the comparison you can eventually get that $f'(1)$ and $f'(0)$ have different signs. Then on the closed interval $[0,1]$ there has to be an absolute maximum which is positive, hence not on $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I think "absolute max on $(a,b)$" is defined as $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)>=f(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. Global maximum is the absolute maximum on the whole domain of $f$.